# What is wrong with this simple char filler?

Tags: c++

It seems and looks really simple but a seemingly random spot of the char array is not filling correctly with 8's. There are no compiler errors either. I'm sorry that this is such a noob question but when I designed a sudoku solver a month ago I didn't have any problems running codes almost identical to this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

//Initiates initial board.
char board[30][27];

//Fills entire board with b's to represent the edges of the board where the pac-man cannot go.
for (int control=0; control<31; control++) {
    for (int control2=0; control2<28; control2++) {
        board[control][control2]='8';
    }
}

//Code here filling the board with spaces representing where the pac-man can go.

//Temporary render of board.
for (int control=0; control<31; control++) {
    for (int control2=0; control2<28; control2++) {
        cout << board[control][control2];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

It apparently has a random segmentation fault.

Answer (score 5):

The segmentation fault is hardly random.  You're overrunning the bounds of your array.  `board[30]` and board[][28] are each one past the end of their respective dimensions.  In this case, you're probably overwriting the return address from `main()`, so your program goes off into the weeds and then dies a horrible death like you're seeing in the segmentation fault. Change your loop conditions to:

```
control < 30
```

and

```
control2 < 27
```

And you should be fine.  You could also change your array's size to `board[31][28]`.

**Most importantly**, you should also learn to use a debugger, which you could use to find the values of the `control` and `control2` variables at the time of failure, which would have solved this problem for you without having to ask here.

Comment: I do have a debugger. It ended normally.

Comment: No it didn't - you said it had a segmentation fault.

Comment: Within the terminal it did. The debugger itself returned nothing. When run, the terminal stopped with a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3):

You are indexing past the maximum of the array.

The maximum index you can do on `board` is `board[29][26]`, because the 30 and 27 you have put are the number of elements and arrays are zero indexed.

Comment: Ok. That fixed my problem, but my reasoning for making them past the number on the board is because if it's a < sign shouldn't it end on the 27 or the 30?

Comment: It does end on 27, but `board[1][27]` is out of bounds because indexing starts from 0. So if you index 27, you are actually attempting to access the 28th element.

Comment: Ok. For some reason even knowing that about the 0 element I thought it would still end on the 27 correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're exceeding the size of your matrix. You have:

```
char board[30][27];
```

But your loops are:

```
for (int control=0; control<31; control++) {
    for (int control2=0; control2<28; control2++) {
```

They will overshoot each dimension by 1.

So either change your matrix to: `char board[31][28];` or cut an iteration off of your loops.